# What is the difference between open and creat system call in c?

Tags: c, unix, file-io

I tried both creat and open system call. Both working in the same way and I can't predict the difference among them. I read the man page. It shows "Open can open device special files, but creat  cannot  create  them". I dont understand what is a special file.

Here is my code,

I am trying to read/write the file using creat system call.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
 int fd;
 int written;
 int bytes_read;
 char buf[]="Hello! Everybody";
 char out[10];
 printf("Buffer String : %s\n",buf);
 fd=creat("output",S_IRWXU);
 if( -1 == fd)
 {
  perror("\nError opening output file");
  exit(0);
 }

 written=write(fd,buf,5);
 if( -1 == written)
 {
  perror("\nFile Write Error");
  exit(0);
 }
 close(fd);
 fd=creat("output",S_IRWXU);

 if( -1 == fd)
 {
  perror("\nfile read error\n");
  exit(0);
 }
 bytes_read=read(fd,out,20);
 printf("\n-->%s\n",out);
 return 0;
}
```

I expted the content "Hello" to printed in the file "output". The file created successfully. But content is empty

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `creat` function *creates* files, but can not open existing file. If using `creat` on an existing file, the file will be truncated and can only be written to. To quote from the [Linux manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/creat):

> `creat()` is equivalent to `open()` with flags equal to `O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC`.

As for device special files, those are all the files in the `/dev` folder. It's simply a way of communicating with a device through normal `read`/`write`/`ioctl` calls.

Answer (score 2):

In early versions of the UNIX System, the second argument to open could be only 0, 1, or 2. There was no way to open a file that didn't already exist. Therefore, a separate system call, creat, was needed to create new files.

Note that:

```
int creat(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);
```

is equivalent to:

```
open(pathname, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, mode);
```

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?